Why does my Barchart date starts at day 2 instead of day 1?
I'm fetching my data using tanstackquery, but the problem I'm encountering right now is when I try to show my data, the day starts at day 2 instead of day.

This is how my I fetch my data from the server.
api/result-overview.tsx
export async function GET(request: Request) {
const { searchParams } = new URL(request.url)
  const timeframe = searchParams.get('timeframe')
  const year = searchParams.get("year")
  const month = searchParams.get("month")


  const queryParams = getHistoryDataSchema.safeParse({
    timeframe,
    year,
    month
  })


  if (!queryParams.success) {
    return Response.json(queryParams.error.message, {
      status: 400
    })
  }


  try {
    const data = await getHistoryData(
      queryParams.data.timeframe, {
      month: queryParams.data.month,
      year: queryParams.data.year
    })


    return Response.json(data)
  } catch (error) {

    return Response.json(error)
  }

}


async function getMonthHistoryData(year: number, month: number): Promise<HistoryData[]> {
  const statuses = ['pending', 'approved', 'done', 'cancel'] as const;
  type Status = typeof statuses[number];

  const results = await Promise.all(
    statuses.map(status =>
      db.scheduleDate.groupBy({
        by: ['day'],
        where: {
          year,
          month,
          soft_delete_scheduleDate: false,
          appointment: {
            soft_delete: false,
            status
          }
        },
        orderBy: [{ day: 'asc' }],
        _count: { _all: true },
      })
    )
  );

  const daysInMonth = new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate();

  const history: HistoryData[] = Array.from({ length: daysInMonth }, (_, i) => {
    const day = i + 1;
    const counts: StatusCounts = {
      pending: 0,
      approved: 0,
      done: 0,
      cancel: 0,
    };

    statuses.forEach((status, index) => {
      const dayData = results[index].find(item => item.day === day);
      counts[status] = dayData ? dayData._count._all : 0;
    });

    return { year, month, day, counts };
  });

  return history;
}

And then I call it in my front side using tanstack query. What I did here is I created a skeleton just to render a few seconds before showing the actual code. the problem i think runs along this line

const date = new Date(year, month, (day ? day + 1 : 1));

History.tsx
  const historyDataQuery = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['overview', 'history', timeFrame, period],
    queryFn: () => fetch(`/api/result-overview?timeframe=${timeFrame}&year=${period.year}&month=${period.month}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => data.map((item: any) => ({
        ...item,
        pending: item.counts.pending,
        approved: item.counts.approved,
        done: item.counts.done,
        cancel: item.counts.cancel,

      })))
  });


return (
<SkeletonWrapper isLoading={historyDataQuery.isFetching}>
              {dataAvailable && (
                <ResponsiveContainer width={"100%"} height={300}>
                  <BarChart data={historyDataQuery.data}>
                    <XAxis
                      stroke="#888888"
                      fontSize={12}
                      tickLine={false}
                      axisLine={false}
                      padding={{ left: 5, right: 5 }}
                      dataKey={(data) => {
                        const { year, month, day } = data;
                        const date = new Date(year, month, (day ? day + 1 : 1));
                        if (timeFrame === "year") {
                          return date.toLocaleDateString("default", {
                            month: "short",
                          });
                        }
                        return date.toLocaleDateString("default", {
                          day: "2-digit",
                        });
                      }}
                    />
                    <YAxis
                      stroke="#888888"
                      fontSize={12}
                      domain={[0, 10]}
                      tickLine={false}
                      axisLine={false}
                    />
                    <Bar dataKey="pending" fill="#eab308" />
                    <Bar dataKey="approved" fill="#10b981" />
                    <Bar dataKey="done" fill="#3b82f6" />
                    <Bar dataKey="cancel" fill="#ef4444" />

                    <Tooltip
                      cursor={{ opacity: 0.1 }}
                      content={(props) => (
                        <CustomToolTip {...props} />
                      )}
                    />
                  </BarChart>


                </ResponsiveContainer>
              )}
            </SkeletonWrapper>
)

But then, when I make it like this

const date = new Date(year, month, day || 0);

The data moves from 12 to 11


Could you share how the fetched data looks?

Most likely the reason is that you already have 1-based day in
const history: HistoryData[] = Array.from({ length: daysInMonth }, (_, i) => {
    const day = i + 1;

and after that you increase it once more
const { year, month, day } = data;
const date = new Date(year, month, (day ? day + 1 : 1));

You can try to log the day from the second fragment before creating the date.

Hello, sorry for very late response, I followed your advice, and did this:
const date = new Date(year, month, day || 1);

The data I fetched is correct, but the problem relies on the barchart itself

You can set interval to 0 to remove the gap.
